# Reshape in different array len with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have two variables `Dog` and `Face`, whose lengths are 921600 and 32256. Then I would like to subtract them as `Dog - Face`. They gave

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Is there any possible way to do the subtraction? It's 1D array.

`Dog`:

```
array([136, 173, 215, ..., 209, 214, 217], dtype=uint8)
```

`Face`:

```
array([61.45223488, 62.01139351, 62.26029798, ..., 41.20464505,
       41.97589833, 42.38825592])
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the shape of the result of this operation?

Comment: It should be subtracted. But I don not know how to reshape them. As you can see, Dog - Face gave error.

Comment: You didn't answer @mkrieger1.   Subtraction of two arrays with unrelated lengths does not make sense - to `numpy` or us humans.  We can't imagine what you are trying to do (at a detailed level).